# Do we need a reference post for Kotlin vs. Java for Android development?

Tags: discussion, canonical

Ever since Kotlin was announced as an official Android language, I've seen numerous questions about the difference (is it replacing Java? Which should I use? Etc.) Would it be worthwhile to just create a canonical/reference post to answer that (like what happened with the `NullReferenceException`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The questions you describe just sound like they should be closed, frankly.  "Which should I use" would be closed any day of the week, regardless of where it came from.

As to whether or not it's "replacing" Java...I'm quite surprised that [Google's own announcement](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/index.html) doesn't clearly illustrate that...

Comment: Yes, there have been several that have been closed as too subjective and/or as recommendation requests. "Is this a replacement for Java?" or "am I going to need to rewrite my app now?" are legitimate. In spite of that particular aspect of the issue being off-topic, though, it might be good to clarify as part of a reference post that Kotlin isn't necessarily "better" than Java *per se" (although I guess that point is primarily opinion-based).